# Vertical space in standalone document

Tags: standalone, vertical-spacing

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\vspace{0.5cm}%                                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I wanted to insert some vertical space above the rectangle using the `\vspace` command. However, it doesn't work.

How to insert a vertical space in a standalone document?

Comment: Try inserting a phantom vertical rule.

Comment: @Bernard I have no idea what it is and how to do it.

Comment: a standalone document is essentially an `\mbox`  @Bernard means use `\rule{0pt}{5cm}` or some such to make white space (use `\rule{1pt}{5cm}` to debug what it is doing and see the rule.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, could you please provide an example?

Comment: just replace the vspace by `\rule{1pt}{5cm}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of `standalone`  , the class provides the option:

`border={〈length (left)〉 〈length (bottom)〉 〈length (right)〉 〈length (top)〉}`

```
\documentclass[
border={0pt 0pt 0pt 1cm}
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
                   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```